# Covariance between factors in CFA (Amos)

Tags: covariance, goodness-of-fit, confirmatory-factor, validity, amos

I ran a Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA) in Amos and obtained a model with high covariance between the factors. James described this covariance in his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCYmyzRZnIY#t=2m48) as alarming.

What can I do to tackle this problem? All my factor loadings are high and it seems to be a good model, except that I have high covariance between the factors.

Additionally, the model fit seems to be poor. All indices indicate that.

Somehow, I was really surprised, because I used the TAM model and the standard items. Therefore, content validity should be given and I expected that construct validity would be given as well.

Comment: High covariance between the factors indicates a violation against construct validity (discriminant validity). The questions for each factor are intercorrelated. Thus, construct validity is not given.

Comment: Try a single factor, instead of two (or more) factors. If the factor correlation is 1.00, a single factor model is equivalent.